# check from view if an certain element is present

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-selectors, haml

I'm using simple form and HAML to make the views and I want to do this:

```
- if ".nested-fields" in page
     # do something
- else
     # do anything
```

if there's the element with the class `.nested-fields` in page, do stuff. How can I verify the element presence from the view?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you could do something like this:

```
if ($(".nested-fields").length > 0){
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: I know that, I want to know how I can do this in rails' views